# Why don't all Font Awesome icons work with boostrapCDN?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

From my understanding, all Font Awesome icons should work with linking this bootstrap stylesheet. But, I just got that one .fa fa-deskto to work, others do not display, the second one for example is:
https://fontawesome.com/icons/bath?f=classic&s=solid

Both icons are also free, but it isn't working.

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/crimson-bird-forked-8fk4dv?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr6i560400062a6634nc7qrr%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr6i560400022a666hgpdsfp%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr6i560400032a66irs556b7%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr6i560400052a66uo98q24m%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clr6i560400022a666hgpdsfp%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr6i560400012a66fks7c4az%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Findex.html%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr6i560400022a666hgpdsfp%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clr6i560400012a66fks7c4az%2522%257D%252C%2522clr6i560400052a66uo98q24m%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr6i560400042a66q5dc490b%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr6i560400052a66uo98q24m%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clr6i560400042a66q5dc490b%2522%257D%252C%2522clr6i560400032a66irs556b7%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr6i560400032a66irs556b7%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <div className="icon">
      <i class="fa fa-desktop"></i>
      <i class="fa-solid fa-bath"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Judging by the pill on the linked page that icon didn't arrive until version `4.7.0`.

Comment: For same reason withdrawing $14,000,000,000 from my bank account does not work; it is not there to obtain.

Comment: Listen man, where you not a beginner in ur life isn't it, meanwhile lemme wire u some cash, seem ur runnin low innit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the provided link does not have the styles for `fa-bath` it must have been added in a later version, please find below link with the latest version where it works fine!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>HTML + CSS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-DTOQO9RWCH3ppGqcWaEA1BIZOC6xxalwEsw9c2QQeAIftl+Vegovlnee1c9QX4TctnWMn13TZye+giMm8e2LwA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
      <div className="icon">
        <i class="fa fa-desktop"></i>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-bath"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

Answer (score -1):

Icon may not available in the "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"

Try "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.1/css/all.min.css" with

```
fas fa-bath
```